# Collecting logs from Kubernetes using OpenTelemetry to send to Splunk

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am trying to collect logs from Kubernetes running on minikube and send it to Splunk Enterprise using Splunk OpenTelemetry Collector.

Followed this guide:
https://lantern.splunk.com/Data_Descriptors/Kubernetes/Getting_Kubernetes_log_data_Into_Splunk_Cloud_Platform_with_OpenTelemetry

Steps are:

1. Configure `values.yaml` file

```
splunkPlatform:
  token: <my HEC token> 
  endpoint: http://localhost:8088/services/collector
  index: observe
splunkObservability:
  accessToken: <my access token> 
  realm: us1

clusterName: minikube
logsEngine: otel
```

2. Add helm chart repository and upgrade value

```
helm upgrade splunk-otel-collector-169935789 -f values.yaml splunk-otel-collector-chart/splunk-otel-collector
```

The collector is deployed using a helm chart

I am able to see the metrics sent to Splunk Observability Cloud. But, no logs in Splunk Enterprise.

I tried sending sample events to the HEC input using curl and it worked.

Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done?